# Angular Translate: How to handle singular and pluralis words?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using [Angular Translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/). That is the easiest way to translate a string, where a word must change depending on singular or pluralis? Like "10 points added" vs. "1 point added"?

Comment: You can always try with more universal message like "Points added: 5". Maybe it isn't your desired solution but it's rough and ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-Translate already has this capability. There are instructions and an example at this page: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/14_pluralization

Comment: I came across that documentation, but wasn't able to see how I transform that into my needs. Can you give me a small example?

Answer (score 0):

From the example of the page, I have tried with "message-format", but adding interpolations makes my code not to work. The problem is at this line:

```
$translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');
```

Although this is not the most elegant way to get it, it works:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
//$translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');

$translateProvider.translations('en', {
   POINTS1: '{{val}} point added',
   POINTSN:'{{val}} points added',
   POINTS: '{NUM, select, one{point} morethanone{points}} added.'
});

$translateProvider.translations('es', {
   POINTS1: '{{val}} punto añadido',
   POINTSN:'{{val}} puntos añadidos',
   POINTS: '{NUM, select, one{punto} morethanone{puntos} añadidos.'
});
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$translate', '$scope', function ($translate, $scope) {
   $scope.points = 10;

   $scope.one_point = function () {
      return points === 1;
   };

   $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
      $translate.use(langKey); 
   };
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!--script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script-->
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js/master/messageformat.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js/master/locale/de.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js/master/locale/fr.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies/master/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/master/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/master/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-cookie/master/angular-translate-storage-cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-local/master/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files/master/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-handler-log/master/angular-translate-handler-log.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div ng-show="Ctrl.one_point()">
    <p translate="POINTS1" translate-values="{ val: {{points}} }"></p>
</div>
<div ng-show="!Ctrl.one_point()">
    <p translate="POINTSN" translate-values="{ val: {{points}} }"></p>
</div>
<button ng-click="changeLanguage('es')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_ES"></button>
<button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN"></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```